# Stopping multiple activities from showing up

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I have it so when you click the notification icon on my app it opens up an activity. The thing is that if you click it over and over it opens the same activity over and over. So when you click the back button you have to go through all of those before going back to the beginning. How could I make it so that if that activity is already there it doesn't reopen it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the `launchMode` section of the [manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

You're looking to add:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to the declaration for your Activity in the manifest. This means that if an instance of the activity is already at the top of the target task, the system will re-use that. Any intent gets delivered to the `onNewIntent` method of that activity.

I'd recommend having a good read of all the options on that page and deciding which one is right for your usage.

Comment: That did it! Was re-reading everything about activies when all along it was a manifest thing...haha. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```